# Aptana 3.0 and virtual env on a ssh shared folder (OS X 10.11.4)

Tags: python, macos, ssh, virtualenv, aptana

I am running Aptana on OS X 10.11.4
I have a Ubuntu VM running on this PC with a ssh shared folder

On the OS X machine, I mount a VM directory with the following command

```
sshfs myapi@192.168.56.101:/home/myapi /Users/lorenzo/dev/vnapi -ovolname=VNAPI
```

I have no problem with this directory. I can read and write any file.

In the mounted dir:
`/Users/lorenzo/dev/vnapi/env` I have a python 2.7 virtual environment

When I try to add this virtualenv interpreter

[image: Interpreter configuration]

I got this error

[image: Add interpreter error]

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What do you see when you click `Details >>`

Comment: In **Details >>** I can see only `No output was in the standard output when`